# Extjs allign only cell text to right

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

i need to align cell text to right side.

```
{
            xtype : 'numbercolumn',
            dataIndex : 'lineAmount',
            id : 'lineAmount',
            header : 'Net Line amount',
            sortable : true,
            width : 150,
            summaryType : 'sum',
            css: 'text-align: rigth;',
            summaryRenderer : Ext.util.renderers.summary.sum,
            editor : {
                xtype : 'numberfield',
                allowBlank : false
            }
```

adding align property does not work for me because it also aligns header text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As answered Mr_Green you can align the text to the right or left using
>   **align**.
>   For header to remain centrally aligned use css as :

```
.x-column-header-inner{
    text-align:center;
 }
```

**Update** :

.....//

```
  {
    xtype : 'grid',
    cls   : 'gridCss',
    ...//other configs
  }
```

.....//

In your app.css file :

```
 .gridCss .x-column-header-inner{
    text-align:center;
 }
```

In your index.jsp

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/resources/css/app.css">
```

Comment: isn`t it the same as adding `css 'text-align : left'` to my column config?

Comment: how to attach that css to my component?

Comment: Fyi: In Extjs 4.2 it must be cls instead of css. There is no configuration called css in Extjs 4.2. I struggled due to that fact because I tried the above code snippets.

Answer (score 6):

There is a config present for `numbercolumn` known as [`align`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Number-cfg-align). just use that.

Whenever you are stuck refer the secha docs which is beautifully designed just for beginners.

I am assuming you are beginner and explaining you how to use docs.. for your clear understanding:

- First go to search field, to search for a component, method, or event or something else.

---

[image]

---

- In your case, let us assume that you have searched for "*numbercolumn*", then you can see the following window which displays all the cofigs, properties, methods etc.. Just hover on them and know what "*numbercolumn*" is related with.
- In your case, you are looking for a config which align's the text to right. then you are mostly looking for key words like txtAlign, align, textAlign, etc..
- Hence, you will find a config, which is by name "*align*". just click on it to learn more about it.

---

[image]

---

- After learning about the cofig "*align*", you might want to test it. For this purpose,  the docs have provided inline code editor which is shown in the below image.
- The code editor has two tabs, "*code editor*" and "*live preview*". The words says everything.
- Just add your changes in "*code editor*" tab and see your result in "*live preview*" tab.

[image]

---

- For example, Adding `align: "right"` code in the below "*code editor*".

---

[image]

---

**Updated**

#### CSS:

```
.columnAlign{
     text-align: right;
}
```

#### extjs

```
tdCls: "columnAlign",
```

Comment: as i said this does not work for me because it aligns both header and cell i need to align only cell text..

Comment: i know how to use documentation, but i think you don`t understand where my problem is. I am not so dumb to do not understand how to add align property to my column config and i`m not begginer user of ExtJs but it changes nothing.

Comment: as you can read in your posted link Sets the alignment of the **header** and rendered columns. Possible values are: 'left', 'center', and 'right'. **Header** is not okay for me as i mentioned before

Comment: @Riku it is ok.. I just added for other users... no offense. I will look in to your solution wait.

Comment: @Riku use `tdCls` instead of `align` and pass a class name which holds `text-align: right`.

Comment: yes it would work in 4.2 but i`m using 3.4 and there is no such property tdCls ;/

Comment: @Riku then I think you should go with Devendra's suggestion.

Comment: Fyi: In Extjs 4.2 it must be cls instead of css. There is no configuration called css in Extjs 4.2. I struggled due to that fact because I tried the above code snippets

Answer (score 0):

Actually thanks both guys for your posts it helped me alot. I have found one solution myself.

I needed to add id property to my column. For example :

```
{
            xtype : 'numbercolumn',
            dataIndex : 'lineAmount',
            id : 'lineAmount',
            header : 'Net Line amount',

        }
```

and then it has its own css class for example :  `.x-grid3-td-lineAmount` so i added suggested css to these classes and it working ok now for me

```
.x-grid3-hd-inner{
    text-align: left;
 }
 .x-grid3-hd-lineAmount{
    text-align: left;
 }
 .x-grid3-td-lineAmount{
    text-align: right;
 }
 .x-grid3-hd-taxAmount{
    text-align: left;
 }
 .x-grid3-td-taxAmount{
    text-align: right;
 }
 .x-grid3-hd-invoiceAmount{
    text-align: left;
 }
 .x-grid3-td-invoiceAmount{
    text-align: right;
 }
```

i think in 4.2 version it is better to use @Mr_Green solution, but in 3.4 this workarround works for me :)